# Can an image have more than one parent_post?

Tags: images

i insert the same image into more posts.
that mean the image have more parent_post?

How do i know the image is attached or unttached?

Answer (score 1):

Images can only be attached to a single post, and they only get attached to the post they were originally uploaded to, and only if it was uploaded to a particular post to begin with. The only way to know if an image is used by a post is to parse the HTML of the posts content and look for its URL.